# How can I have an ImageView with TouchListener together with Doubletap Listener in Android

Tags: android, android-imageview, android-gesture, android-touch-event

I have an imageView with a simple touchlistener which on ACTION.UP it get the color of the bitmap pixel.

```
img.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener(){

        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event)
        {

            int action = event.getAction();
            int x = (int) event.getX();
            int y = (int) event.getY();
            switch(action){

                case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:

                    int pixel = bitmap.getPixel(x, y);

                    if (pixel == Color.parseColor("#94e3f9")) {
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Blue Color", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                    if (pixel == Color.parseColor("#f0c828")) {
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Yellow Color", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                    if (pixel == Color.parseColor("#b3522c")) {
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Red Color", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                    break;
            }

            return true;
        }
    });
```

At the same time I want to have the ability of doubletap inside the imageView and do something else like opening a dialog box.

How I can implement and combine this?

Comment: have you checked this class https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener.html?

Comment: You mean instead of the simple touchlistener to have them all in one gesture listener?

Comment: yep.. the callbacks will help you with the Double/Tap

Comment: any structural example of that?

Comment: there are example here : https://developer.android.com/training/gestures/detector.html

Comment: how to connect it with imageview eg img.mDetector.setOnDoubleTapListener(this); ?

Comment: ImageButton maybe?